# Add or Subtract

Tags: java

basically what im trying to do is have a number of stock (lets say its, 100) and an inventory list displaying the stock sold or added . how do i code it to say if it is a minus number , on the inventory list, (e.g -55) to take it away or if it is a positive number (i.e 45 to add it on instead of taking it away) ??

Cheers

Comment: so you want 100-55 and 100+45?

Answer (score 4):

Adding a negative number is the same as subtracting, so just add in both cases; you don't need any special handling for positive and negative numbers.

Comment: cheers guys , i figured it out , i've literally hit a mental wall because it is so late here in ireland and i have been on it for ages :P

Comment: @user1347515 Maybe time for bed ;) wouldn't want you to forget the alphabet next (just being a little cheeky I hope you'll forgive)

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
stocks += boughtOrSoldQuantity;
```

If `boughtOrSoldQuantity` is negative, `stocks` will be reduced by that quantity; otherwise, it will be increased.

Answer (score 1):

mathematically `100 + -45` is the same as `100 - 45` so in both cases you can just add the number.